# How To Start Expo Web In A Specific Browser?

Tags: react-native, expo, expo-web

On my Mac, I have Chrome, Firefox, and Safari installed. Safari is set as the default system browser.

Launching expo web using;

```
expo start -w
```

works. However, it launches the URI in Chrome rather than Safari. If I delete the Chrome browser, expo will launch in Safari. However I would like to continue with multiple browsers installed.

How can this be overridden so I can choose Safari?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

This issue provides the answer:

https://github.com/expo/expo-cli/issues/1004

> As a workaround, you can force a different browser using the BROWSER
>   environment variable.
>
> For me, env BROWSER=firefox expo start works.

For different browsers, use one of the following:

*Safari*

```
env BROWSER=safari expo start -w
```

*Firefox*

```
env BROWSER=firefox expo start -w
```

*Chrome*

```
env BROWSER=Google\ Chrome expo start -w
```

*Brave*

```
env BROWSER=Brave\ Browser expo start -w
```

Answer (score 1):

For Windows...

I created project with `expo init` and for developing i just run this batch:

```
set BROWSER=chrome
yarn web
```

It works if there is this setting present in package.json

```
{
  "scripts": {
    "web": "expo start --web",
  }
}
```

OR you can simly make the batch file look like this

```
set BROWSER=chrome
expo start -w
```

Answer (score -1):

I found this work well:

expo start

then,
shift+d

this will toggle on and off webpage launch

this hit shows right after expo start command